# Inner query filter double entries

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL, and this is my first ever query. 
The query works, but it produces about 31034 results.
However, it should be a mere 100 results... I got a TON of duplicate entries.

How come my query shows the double entries?

My query:

```
SELECT 
    server_ram.server_id, server.brandtype, server_ram.ram_max 
FROM 
    server 
INNER JOIN 
    server_ram 
WHERE 
    server.brandtype = 'Microcloud (X10SLE-F)' 
    AND server_ram.ram_max LIKE '%Registered%';
```

Results:

```
| 876 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered     |
| 877 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered     |
| 878 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered     |
| 879 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered     |
| 881 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered     |
| 882 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered     |
| 883 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered     |
| 884 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered     |
| 885 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered     |
| 886 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered     |
| 887 | Microcloud (X10SLE-F) | DDR3 ECC Registered     |
```

Comment: You have no `ON` clause to join the two tables.

Comment: Please describe exactly what data is in each table

Comment: @Florius Help us help you.  That's all you give.  How do you expect us to help you???  Where's your table structure???  Sample input???  Expected output???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you intend something like this:

```
SELECT sr.server_id, s.brandtype, sr.ram_max
FROM server s INNER JOIN
     server_ram sr
     ON sr.server_id = s.server_id
WHERE s.brandtype = 'Microcloud (X10SLE-F)' AND sr.ram_max LIKE '%Registered%';
```

Notes:

- When using `JOIN`, you always want an `ON` clause.  I speculate that you are using MySQL, where the clause is optional.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- It is unclear what the columns are for joining the tables.  The above is just a guess.

Comment: `#1054 - Unknown column 's.server_id' in 'on clause'`, am I not getting it?

Comment: @Florius You don't give your table structure, how do you expect us to know what columns are in your table????  He just assumes you have `server_id` column in your `server` table.  Learn to debug.  Replace it with whatever column connect the 2 tables.  You also don't tag which dbms you are using.  He's assuming you are using `MySQL`.  So tag your question properly.

Comment: @Florius . . . As mentioned in the answer, I just guessed on what the `join` keys are.

Comment: My apologies @Eric. That's my bad. I am not familiar enough with (MySQL) to even provide the requested information, let me try:
I'm using MySQL. Because of character limit: https://pastebin.com/Sgvp9Ngg

Again, my apologies, if I do anything wrong, let me know!!

Comment: Oh I managed to fix this, with the `ON` addition! Thank you very much.
I apologize for not providing full information, I will make sure this happens next time.